# При создании папки через CMS acl выставляются некорректно

Tags: cms, битрикс

Добрый день! Есть проблема, при создании папки в админке CMS(Bitrix) маска, которая выставляется на папку такая `mask::r-x` , полный вывод getfacl приведен ниже. При создании папки через mkdir от имени пользователя, под которым работает вебсервер права стоят корректные. Папка test-folder создана в админке CMS.

```
# file: test-folder/
# owner: web-server
# group: web-server
user::rwx
user:web-server:rwx                 #effective:r-x
user:webdev:rwx        #effective:r-x
group::rwx                      #effective:r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:web-server:rwx
default:user:webdev:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Итак, разобрался, дело в том, что команда `chmod` при изменении прав на группу меняет маску. У битрикса есть файл `dbconn.php`, в котором значение файлов, создаваемых по умолчанию стояло 644, поэтому в созданных каталогах и стояла маска r-x.